# Take pride of place in my heart

Tags: idioms

I was wondering about the idiomatic structure of “take pride of place”
And I wanted to know that whether I can use this structure as in the context, which is related to my interest;
“La Nausèe by Sartre has taken pride of place in my heart.”
Is that correct?

Comment: pride of place refers to physical places, usually.  It's Nausea by Sartre. by the way.

Comment: Thank you ever so much, but if I wanted to use it as a metaphorical item, it would be correct?

Comment: Yes, sourena. But let me tell you this: putting the word nausea in a sentence followed by pride of place is quite odd, even though La Nausée is the book. Is it really  your "heart" that was taken with it? Perhaps you can find another expression? :) With regard to hearts, we often say: has a a special place in my heart.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) yes, honestly, I’ve got recently familiar with this idiom, and I wanted to see whether I can use it as a way to impress my interest or not :) btw, thanks a million for your clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One distinction: although the phrase "pride of place" is often used with the verb "take," it seems it most often uses it in a way that still describes an existing order, not a *change* to that order. From [this dictionary entry](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/have-take-pride-of-place): "A portrait of his grandfather takes pride of place in the entrance hall." That doesn't mean that the portrait has *moved into* the most important position, simply that it occupies it.

Your construction would be immediately understood, but if you mean that Sartre's novel has *become more* prominent in your heart than it used to be, some other verb might be appropriate. Perhaps "*Nausea* by Sartre **has moved into** pride of place in my heart," though even that sounds just a bit odd. It might be smart to avoid the idiom entirely, with something like "has moved into the foremost place in my heart."

By the way, the confusion between "nausea" as a word and as a title is lessened if you italicize it, as one does for a full-length book.

Comment: Thank you so much for your clarification